# loging in with 'su' command in one line

Tags: linux, terminal

How can I loging with su command in one line in the terminal?
I know that sudo command can do that:

```
echo [password] | sudo -S [command]
```

But when I try to imply it in su command :

```
echo [password] | su [username]
```

I get en error:

```
standard in must be tty
```

I don't have access to the sudo account (so I can't access and edit the sudoers file)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as required for Stackoverflow questions. Your question may be appropriate on other sites such as [unix.se] but do check their help first before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo su -`.

And yes, this question seems to be Off-Topic.